# Simple Implementation of CKEDITOR "allowContent" in CKEDITOR 5

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am bringing back text from a DB using PHP/Ajax. The text in the DB has HTML markup inline and CKEDITOR displays most of the HTML as plain text with the HTML markup rendered correctly. I am trying to use the HTML "u" tags inline in my text in the DB but with CKEDITOR5 it does not render underlines from HTML. Is there simple way to define **allowedContent** as it was in CKEditor 4 to allow underline HTML tags.

Current CKEDITOR Code:

```
ckeditor = ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#message' ))
             .then( editor => {
               ckeditor = editor
             } )
            .catch( error => {
              console.error( error );
            } );
        });
```

Comment: Does this help: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/migrate.html

Comment: I ended up reverting back to ckeditor4 since there is no direct usage of the same functions/attributes in CKEDITOR5. But thank you though!